# Duplicating Windows desktop more than one time

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, directx-11

I need to duplicate desktop in a set of windows. I did it as follows:

```
ID3D11Device* Device;
D3D11CreateDevice(...&Device)
...
IDXGIOutputDuplication* DeskDupl;
IDXGIOutput1::DuplicateOutput(Device, DeskDupl);
```

For one window to duplicate the desktop it works OK, but for another window I get E_INVALIDARG on `DuplicateOutput()`. MSDN says it means: `The calling application is already duplicating this desktop output.`

Is it possible to duplicate desktop to a few windows, not just one?

Comment: Surely, once you've got a texture with the desktop content, you can display it in as many windows as you like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented this as creating a hidden window at coordinates (-32000, -32000), which is targeted as the primary screen output in `DirectX IDXGIOutput1::DuplicateOutput()`.

After being created, this hidden window is mirrored to the required windows with using DWM as shown in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24226255/209406):

```
hr = DwmRegisterThumbnail();
hr = DwmUpdateThumbnailProperties();
```

The resulting performance is sufficient even for a few big (1920x1200) windows. The CPU load is no higher than 5%.

Answer (score 1):

Seems not with your approach, see remmars section of [IDXGIOutput1::DuplicateOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method

> By default, only four processes can use a IDXGIOutputDuplication
>   interface at the same time within a single session. **A process can
>   have only one desktop duplication interface on a single desktop
>   output;** however, that process can have a desktop duplication
>   interface for each output that is part of the desktop.

But you might do it in other ways, if you just want to render same scene in different windows, I recommend using multiple swap-chains.

Comment: What does "using multiple swap-chains" mean? Calling CreateSwapChainForHwnd for every hWnd, like CreateSwapChainForHwnd(device, hWnd[], ..., &swapChain[i]) ?

Comment: @AntonK I found a sample which using DirectX 9 [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/369502-multiple-devices-vs-multiple-swap-chains/) (the code was in 10th floor), you can try to update it to DirectX 11.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful to better understand DirectX