# Mirroring one window to another

Tags: windows, winapi

I have an MFC window object with all the information about it. I'm looking for a way to mirror it to another window so that both windows look identical. I've heard it's possible through DWM window previewing.

How it can be done?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. As far as the API is concerned, all windows are completely independent of each other. There is no notion of a "linked" window that inherits its properties from another window. Can you describe exactly what you're hoping to accomplish and why you think you need this functionality? Maybe then we could point you in a better direction.

Comment: I need to duplicate a desktop to another desktop. So I created desktop-wide window and rendered it with the desktop via DirectX. Somehow I cannot organize output to two windows instead of one and I'm trying different approaches.
Anyway in this question I'm thinking about mirroring a window. I've heard it's possible to do it via DWM preview.

Comment: Create a DWM thumbnail.l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was that I used DWM thumbnailing for the source window:

```
hr = DwmRegisterThumbnail();
hr = DwmUpdateThumbnailProperties();
```

as @raymond-chen suggested.