# Preview of some own application

Tags: c#, c++, windows, user-interface

I want to have some own application which is placed on one display (form is visible on that display). On the second display I want to show preview what is hapenning in that application. For example application can be used for scrolling the pdf document and so on and in the next monitor I want to see where is PDF scrolled and so on.

I want this function because we will have to two working people on same PC. One on Tablet, second one on Main screen of PC.

I just want advice to ways how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mirroring one window to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282575/mirroring-one-window-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

What basically you need is to extend the display between 2 monitors / displays.
So if you open a PDF viewer, the right most preview display will be available in second monitor and left most actual viewing of the document, happens in primary monitor.

Assuming you are using windows, please refer [extending display](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/move-windows-between-multiple-monitors#1TC=windows-7) .
If you want to generate some application, which should use this feature when available, please refer to [muti monitor example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162826(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Yes, I am using extended displays. So preview do you mean small preview that is visible in the taskbar when I go with mouse on taskbar icon of pdf? If yes, I  would like to have preview that is not in taskbar but as some window application which can be placed everywhere on the monitor and can have different sizes that preview showed in taskbar.

Comment: No. I was talking about preview as in this image : https://bestwinsoft.com/images/jdownloads/screenshots/bws_adobe_reader_3.jpg

Comment: hm, but PDF was only example. I want to use this for all types of windows that are showed on tablet display.

Comment: OK. Then basically you need to develop your own application on the lines of taskbar previews. Then launch that application in the extended display / or second display and preview the screen as seen in primary display. For more information on how taskbar provides the preview of applications, please refer : https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/yochay/Programming-the-Windows-7-Taskbar--Custom-Previews-and-Thumbnail-Clips